# SQL Order by giving weird results - id keeps changing every so often - why?

Tags: sql-server

```
set statistics time on;
DECLARE @sort_order varchar(10)
DECLARE @order_by varchar(10)
set @sort_order = 'DESC'; 
set @order_by = 'lastmodified';
WITH results AS
(
    SELECT id, title, LastModified, ROW_NUMBER() over
    (ORDER BY 
        CASE @sort_order
          WHEN 'ASC' THEN
               CASE @order_by
                    WHEN 'lastmodified' THEN CAST(LastModified AS VARCHAR(50))
                    WHEN 'title' THEN title
                    ELSE CAST(LastModified AS VARCHAR(50))
               END
          ELSE '1'
     END ASC,
     CASE @sort_order
          WHEN 'DESC' THEN
               CASE @order_by
                    WHEN 'lastmodified' THEN CAST(LastModified AS VARCHAR(50))
                    WHEN 'title' THEN title
                    ELSE CAST(LastModified AS VARCHAR(50))
               END
          ELSE '1'
     END DESC) RowNum

    FROM dbo.EmploymentOpportunities
    where CompanyId = 148

)
SELECT id, title, LastModified, (select count(*) from results) totalcount
FROM results
where RowNum between 1 and 9 OPTION(Maxdop 8)
```

Comment: I tried removing the Maxdop and adding an Order By in the outer query, but the results are still unpredictable. Based on your response and all the criteria that can affect the order, would i be better using multiple specific Order By SP's, called from C#, than having one single complicated SP ?

Comment: If you have ORDER BY on the outer query, and the resulting order is unpredictable, then you have found a bug. Of course, you'll need to prove it.

Comment: set statistics time on;
WITH results AS
(
    SELECT id, title, LastModified, ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY lastmodified asc) RowNum
 FROM dbo.EmploymentOpportunities
 where CompanyId = 148
     
)
SELECT id, title, LastModified, (select count(*) from results) totalcount
FROM results
where RowNum between 1 and 9 OPTION(Maxdop 8)

Comment: The above query works perfectly, but the Order By is hard coded and not passed from C#.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what this has to do with C# or what you mean by "Order By is hard coded." The query you posted in a comment (don't do that, it's absolutely impossible to read) doesn't have an ORDER BY either. Really not following your logic here.

Comment: In the original SP the Sort Order and Sort Type parameters are passed to the SP. In the second query i placed in the 'add comment' section, the Order By lastmodified asc is hard coded in the query, which actually works, but does not have the ability to receive passed variables. Does this make things clearer?

Comment: No, if you are now asking a different question in the comments than you asked originally, perhaps you should open a new question, and include the code you're actually talking about, instead of just describing your code in a comment...

Answer (score 3):

Well, your outer query doesn't *have* an `ORDER BY`. If you add one, it will be much more predictable. e.g.

```
...
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 and 9
ORDER BY id 
OPTION (MAXDOP 8);
```

If you don't have an `ORDER BY`, SQL Server is free to return the results in any order it deems most efficient. In a lot of cases this behavior will be consistent and predictable (which is not the same as guaranteed); however, it can change between query executions based on a variety of factors - data skew, statistics changes, plan cache flush, buffer pool flush, aged out plan, service restart, service pack, cumulative update, upgrade, failover, etc. etc. etc.

When parallelism is involved, it is much less reliable, because different threads could be handing different portions of the data, and finish at different times. Since you don't have an `ORDER BY`, SQL Server just re-assembles the data as the threads finish, and doesn't bother re-sorting in any way, because you didn't say you cared.

***IF YOU WANT A CERTAIN ORDER, ALWAYS USE ORDER BY ON THE OUTER QUERY. PERIOD.***

Comment: If you don't specify ORDER BY, ordering is up to SQL server internals (i.e. nothing can be guaranteed).